# names that have 10 highest values for each column with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get  names that have the 10 highest values in each column by using only VBA.
The list of column names is specified in an argument, and the number of columns and rows are not fixed, so I need something dynamic.
This is my data

```html
names   mod1  mod2   ...   modn

name1    1     5     ...    3
name2    2           ...    1
name3          2     ...    
name4    9     13    ...    22
 ...     
namen    61    7            4
```

And i want a result like that. 
For example a list of two columns mod8 and mod13.
is it possible by using only vba, and how should i do it, i'm new in vba.

```html
        name          value

mod8    name8         123
        name1135      92
        name1136      22
        name23037     17
        name1138      15
        name1139      6
        name5140      5
        name1141      4
        name1142      2
        name1143      1

mod13   name2         7
        name1         6
        name5         3
        name7         1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a SQL statement too to accomplish this one. For this to work you'll need to make sure you have column headers, add a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.8 Library` or greater, and the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` driver installed (it comes with MS Access).

Make sure to update the sheet references, as I made up a contrived example.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTopTenValues()
    Dim ws          As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Dim outsheet    As Worksheet: Set outsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim lastCol     As Long
    Dim conn        As ADODB.Connection: Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs          As ADODB.Recordset: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql         As String
    Dim i           As Long

    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
    conn.Open
    lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 2 To lastCol
        sql = "Select top 10 [names], [" & ws.Cells(1, i).Value2 & "] from [Sheet3$] order by [" & ws.Cells(1, i).Value2 & "] desc"
        rs.Open sql, conn
        lastRow = outsheet.Cells(outsheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        outsheet.Range("A" & lastRow).CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
    Next

    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that the data appears in  Sheet 1.Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim R As Long, C As Long, LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long, LastRowInitial As Long, LastRowSecond As Long
    Dim strmodName As String, strName As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowInitial = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For C = 2 To LastColumn
            strmodName = .Cells(1, C).Value

            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Row

            For R = 2 To LastRow
                strName = .Cells(R, 1).Value

                If .Cells(R, C).Value > 10 Then

                    LastRowSecond = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

                    If LastRowSecond = 1 And .Cells(1, 7).Value = "" Then
                        .Cells(LastRowSecond, LastColumn + 3).Value = "Name"
                        .Cells(LastRowSecond, LastColumn + 4).Value = "Value"
                        .Cells(LastRowSecond + 2, LastColumn + 2).Value = strmodName
                        .Cells(LastRowSecond + 2, LastColumn + 3).Value = strName
                        .Cells(LastRowSecond + 2, LastColumn + 4).Value = .Cells(R, C).Value
                    Else
                        If R = 2 Then
                            .Cells(LastRowSecond + 1, 6).Value = strmodName
                        End If
                            .Cells(LastRowSecond + 1, LastColumn + 3).Value = strName
                            .Cells(LastRowSecond + 1, LastColumn + 4).Value = .Cells(R, C).Value
                    End If

                End If

            Next R

        Next C

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, it's working, thanks. Still, one small issue, how can I order values for each mod and get the name of each value ordered in the same line